# How to set a parameter for loading data or embedding data in d3?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, loading

At work, I try to use d3 for visualization. Since I cannot install a web server there (no permission), I try to support two options:

a) Loading data from a delimited file (it does work with the firefox version some of us have

b) Embedding (copying) data into a html tag (unfortunately, it doesn't works d3.dsv() , but just with  d3.csv.parse ()

I succeded setting up a d3 program that supports both, however I want to switch between the two options by setting a parameter. E.g. if the variable nameOfFile == "" then the code should read the data from the 'pre' tag, otherwise form the file.

My current program is now supporting the b) part: reading data from the 'pre' tag.
To switch back to reading from a file, I have to reinstate the outcommented lines with 1:, 2: and 4:, plus to comment out the line with 3:

Can anyone show me a more elegant way to accomplish with (by branching off a parameter)?

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang=en>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>Multiples Streamgraph</title>

    <style>
        body {
          font: 12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
          margin:  0 auto;
          position: relative;
          width: 960px;
        }
        .axis path {
          fill: none;
          stroke: #000;
          shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
        .axis line {
          fill: none;
          stroke: #000;
          shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
        form {
          position: absolute;
          right: 10px;
          top: 10px;
        }
        .group-label {
          text-anchor: end;
        }
        pre#data {
          display:none;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <pre id="data">
symbol,date,price
MSFT,Jan 2000,39.81
MSFT,Feb 2000,36.35
MSFT,Mar 2000,43.22
MSFT,Apr 2000,28.37
MSFT,May 2000,25.45
MSFT,Jun 2000,32.54
MSFT,Jul 2000,28.4
MSFT,Aug 2000,28.4
MSFT,Sep 2000,24.53
MSFT,Oct 2000,28.02
MSFT,Nov 2000,23.34
MSFT,Dec 2000,17.65
MSFT,Jan 2001,24.84
MSFT,Feb 2001,24
MSFT,Mar 2001,22.25
MSFT,Apr 2001,27.56
MSFT,May 2001,28.14
MSFT,Jun 2001,29.7
MSFT,Jul 2001,26.93
MSFT,Aug 2001,23.21
MSFT,Sep 2001,20.82
MSFT,Oct 2001,23.65
MSFT,Nov 2001,26.12
MSFT,Dec 2001,26.95
MSFT,Jan 2002,25.92
MSFT,Feb 2002,23.73
MSFT,Mar 2002,24.53
MSFT,Apr 2002,21.26
MSFT,May 2002,20.71
MSFT,Jun 2002,22.25
MSFT,Jul 2002,19.52
MSFT,Aug 2002,19.97
MSFT,Sep 2002,17.79
MSFT,Oct 2002,21.75
MSFT,Nov 2002,23.46
MSFT,Dec 2002,21.03
MSFT,Jan 2003,19.31
MSFT,Feb 2003,19.34
MSFT,Mar 2003,19.76
MSFT,Apr 2003,20.87
MSFT,May 2003,20.09
MSFT,Jun 2003,20.93
MSFT,Jul 2003,21.56
MSFT,Aug 2003,21.65
MSFT,Sep 2003,22.69
MSFT,Oct 2003,21.45
MSFT,Nov 2003,21.1
MSFT,Dec 2003,22.46
MSFT,Jan 2004,22.69
MSFT,Feb 2004,21.77
MSFT,Mar 2004,20.46
MSFT,Apr 2004,21.45
MSFT,May 2004,21.53
MSFT,Jun 2004,23.44
MSFT,Jul 2004,23.38
MSFT,Aug 2004,22.47
MSFT,Sep 2004,22.76
MSFT,Oct 2004,23.02
MSFT,Nov 2004,24.6
MSFT,Dec 2004,24.52
MSFT,Jan 2005,24.11
MSFT,Feb 2005,23.15
MSFT,Mar 2005,22.24
MSFT,Apr 2005,23.28
MSFT,May 2005,23.82
MSFT,Jun 2005,22.93
MSFT,Jul 2005,23.64
MSFT,Aug 2005,25.35
MSFT,Sep 2005,23.83
MSFT,Oct 2005,23.8
MSFT,Nov 2005,25.71
MSFT,Dec 2005,24.29
MSFT,Jan 2006,26.14
MSFT,Feb 2006,25.04
MSFT,Mar 2006,25.36
MSFT,Apr 2006,22.5
MSFT,May 2006,21.19
MSFT,Jun 2006,21.8
MSFT,Jul 2006,22.51
MSFT,Aug 2006,24.13
MSFT,Sep 2006,25.68
MSFT,Oct 2006,26.96
MSFT,Nov 2006,27.66
MSFT,Dec 2006,28.13
MSFT,Jan 2007,29.07
MSFT,Feb 2007,26.63
MSFT,Mar 2007,26.35
MSFT,Apr 2007,28.3
MSFT,May 2007,29.11
MSFT,Jun 2007,27.95
MSFT,Jul 2007,27.5
MSFT,Aug 2007,27.34
MSFT,Sep 2007,28.04
MSFT,Oct 2007,35.03
MSFT,Nov 2007,32.09
MSFT,Dec 2007,34
MSFT,Jan 2008,31.13
MSFT,Feb 2008,26.07
MSFT,Mar 2008,27.21
MSFT,Apr 2008,27.34
MSFT,May 2008,27.25
MSFT,Jun 2008,26.47
MSFT,Jul 2008,24.75
MSFT,Aug 2008,26.36
MSFT,Sep 2008,25.78
MSFT,Oct 2008,21.57
MSFT,Nov 2008,19.66
MSFT,Dec 2008,18.91
MSFT,Jan 2009,16.63
MSFT,Feb 2009,15.81
MSFT,Mar 2009,17.99
MSFT,Apr 2009,19.84
MSFT,May 2009,20.59
MSFT,Jun 2009,23.42
MSFT,Jul 2009,23.18
MSFT,Aug 2009,24.43
MSFT,Sep 2009,25.49
MSFT,Oct 2009,27.48
MSFT,Nov 2009,29.27
MSFT,Dec 2009,30.34
MSFT,Jan 2010,28.05
MSFT,Feb 2010,28.67
MSFT,Mar 2010,28.8
AMZN,Jan 2000,64.56
AMZN,Feb 2000,68.87
AMZN,Mar 2000,67
AMZN,Apr 2000,55.19
AMZN,May 2000,48.31
AMZN,Jun 2000,36.31
AMZN,Jul 2000,30.12
AMZN,Aug 2000,41.5
AMZN,Sep 2000,38.44
AMZN,Oct 2000,36.62
AMZN,Nov 2000,24.69
AMZN,Dec 2000,15.56
AMZN,Jan 2001,17.31
AMZN,Feb 2001,10.19
AMZN,Mar 2001,10.23
AMZN,Apr 2001,15.78
AMZN,May 2001,16.69
AMZN,Jun 2001,14.15
AMZN,Jul 2001,12.49
AMZN,Aug 2001,8.94
AMZN,Sep 2001,5.97
AMZN,Oct 2001,6.98
AMZN,Nov 2001,11.32
AMZN,Dec 2001,10.82
AMZN,Jan 2002,14.19
AMZN,Feb 2002,14.1
AMZN,Mar 2002,14.3
AMZN,Apr 2002,16.69
AMZN,May 2002,18.23
AMZN,Jun 2002,16.25
AMZN,Jul 2002,14.45
AMZN,Aug 2002,14.94
AMZN,Sep 2002,15.93
AMZN,Oct 2002,19.36
AMZN,Nov 2002,23.35
AMZN,Dec 2002,18.89
AMZN,Jan 2003,21.85
AMZN,Feb 2003,22.01
AMZN,Mar 2003,26.03
AMZN,Apr 2003,28.69
AMZN,May 2003,35.89
AMZN,Jun 2003,36.32
AMZN,Jul 2003,41.64
AMZN,Aug 2003,46.32
AMZN,Sep 2003,48.43
AMZN,Oct 2003,54.43
AMZN,Nov 2003,53.97
AMZN,Dec 2003,52.62
AMZN,Jan 2004,50.4
AMZN,Feb 2004,43.01
AMZN,Mar 2004,43.28
AMZN,Apr 2004,43.6
AMZN,May 2004,48.5
AMZN,Jun 2004,54.4
AMZN,Jul 2004,38.92
AMZN,Aug 2004,38.14
AMZN,Sep 2004,40.86
AMZN,Oct 2004,34.13
AMZN,Nov 2004,39.68
AMZN,Dec 2004,44.29
AMZN,Jan 2005,43.22
AMZN,Feb 2005,35.18
AMZN,Mar 2005,34.27
AMZN,Apr 2005,32.36
AMZN,May 2005,35.51
AMZN,Jun 2005,33.09
AMZN,Jul 2005,45.15
AMZN,Aug 2005,42.7
AMZN,Sep 2005,45.3
AMZN,Oct 2005,39.86
AMZN,Nov 2005,48.46
AMZN,Dec 2005,47.15
AMZN,Jan 2006,44.82
AMZN,Feb 2006,37.44
AMZN,Mar 2006,36.53
AMZN,Apr 2006,35.21
AMZN,May 2006,34.61
AMZN,Jun 2006,38.68
AMZN,Jul 2006,26.89
AMZN,Aug 2006,30.83
AMZN,Sep 2006,32.12
AMZN,Oct 2006,38.09
AMZN,Nov 2006,40.34
AMZN,Dec 2006,39.46
AMZN,Jan 2007,37.67
AMZN,Feb 2007,39.14
AMZN,Mar 2007,39.79
AMZN,Apr 2007,61.33
AMZN,May 2007,69.14
AMZN,Jun 2007,68.41
AMZN,Jul 2007,78.54
AMZN,Aug 2007,79.91
AMZN,Sep 2007,93.15
AMZN,Oct 2007,89.15
AMZN,Nov 2007,90.56
AMZN,Dec 2007,92.64
AMZN,Jan 2008,77.7
AMZN,Feb 2008,64.47
AMZN,Mar 2008,71.3
AMZN,Apr 2008,78.63
AMZN,May 2008,81.62
AMZN,Jun 2008,73.33
AMZN,Jul 2008,76.34
AMZN,Aug 2008,80.81
AMZN,Sep 2008,72.76
AMZN,Oct 2008,57.24
AMZN,Nov 2008,42.7
AMZN,Dec 2008,51.28
AMZN,Jan 2009,58.82
AMZN,Feb 2009,64.79
AMZN,Mar 2009,73.44
AMZN,Apr 2009,80.52
AMZN,May 2009,77.99
AMZN,Jun 2009,83.66
AMZN,Jul 2009,85.76
AMZN,Aug 2009,81.19
AMZN,Sep 2009,93.36
AMZN,Oct 2009,118.81
AMZN,Nov 2009,135.91
AMZN,Dec 2009,134.52
AMZN,Jan 2010,125.41
AMZN,Feb 2010,118.4
AMZN,Mar 2010,128.82
IBM,Jan 2000,100.52
IBM,Feb 2000,92.11
IBM,Mar 2000,106.11
IBM,Apr 2000,99.95
IBM,May 2000,96.31
IBM,Jun 2000,98.33
IBM,Jul 2000,100.74
IBM,Aug 2000,118.62
IBM,Sep 2000,101.19
IBM,Oct 2000,88.5
IBM,Nov 2000,84.12
IBM,Dec 2000,76.47
IBM,Jan 2001,100.76
IBM,Feb 2001,89.98
IBM,Mar 2001,86.63
IBM,Apr 2001,103.7
IBM,May 2001,100.82
IBM,Jun 2001,102.35
IBM,Jul 2001,94.87
IBM,Aug 2001,90.25
IBM,Sep 2001,82.82
IBM,Oct 2001,97.58
IBM,Nov 2001,104.5
IBM,Dec 2001,109.36
IBM,Jan 2002,97.54
IBM,Feb 2002,88.82
IBM,Mar 2002,94.15
IBM,Apr 2002,75.82
IBM,May 2002,72.97
IBM,Jun 2002,65.31
IBM,Jul 2002,63.86
IBM,Aug 2002,68.52
IBM,Sep 2002,53.01
IBM,Oct 2002,71.76
IBM,Nov 2002,79.16
IBM,Dec 2002,70.58
IBM,Jan 2003,71.22
IBM,Feb 2003,71.13
IBM,Mar 2003,71.57
IBM,Apr 2003,77.47
IBM,May 2003,80.48
IBM,Jun 2003,75.42
IBM,Jul 2003,74.28
IBM,Aug 2003,75.12
IBM,Sep 2003,80.91
IBM,Oct 2003,81.96
IBM,Nov 2003,83.08
IBM,Dec 2003,85.05
IBM,Jan 2004,91.06
IBM,Feb 2004,88.7
IBM,Mar 2004,84.41
IBM,Apr 2004,81.04
IBM,May 2004,81.59
IBM,Jun 2004,81.19
IBM,Jul 2004,80.19
IBM,Aug 2004,78.17
IBM,Sep 2004,79.13
IBM,Oct 2004,82.84
IBM,Nov 2004,87.15
IBM,Dec 2004,91.16
IBM,Jan 2005,86.39
IBM,Feb 2005,85.78
IBM,Mar 2005,84.66
IBM,Apr 2005,70.77
IBM,May 2005,70.18
IBM,Jun 2005,68.93
IBM,Jul 2005,77.53
IBM,Aug 2005,75.07
IBM,Sep 2005,74.7
IBM,Oct 2005,76.25
IBM,Nov 2005,82.98
IBM,Dec 2005,76.73
IBM,Jan 2006,75.89
IBM,Feb 2006,75.09
IBM,Mar 2006,77.17
IBM,Apr 2006,77.05
IBM,May 2006,75.04
IBM,Jun 2006,72.15
IBM,Jul 2006,72.7
IBM,Aug 2006,76.35
IBM,Sep 2006,77.26
IBM,Oct 2006,87.06
IBM,Nov 2006,86.95
IBM,Dec 2006,91.9
IBM,Jan 2007,93.79
IBM,Feb 2007,88.18
IBM,Mar 2007,89.44
IBM,Apr 2007,96.98
IBM,May 2007,101.54
IBM,Jun 2007,100.25
IBM,Jul 2007,105.4
IBM,Aug 2007,111.54
IBM,Sep 2007,112.6
IBM,Oct 2007,111
IBM,Nov 2007,100.9
IBM,Dec 2007,103.7
IBM,Jan 2008,102.75
IBM,Feb 2008,109.64
IBM,Mar 2008,110.87
IBM,Apr 2008,116.23
IBM,May 2008,125.14
IBM,Jun 2008,114.6
IBM,Jul 2008,123.74
IBM,Aug 2008,118.16
IBM,Sep 2008,113.53
IBM,Oct 2008,90.24
IBM,Nov 2008,79.65
IBM,Dec 2008,82.15
IBM,Jan 2009,89.46
IBM,Feb 2009,90.32
IBM,Mar 2009,95.09
IBM,Apr 2009,101.29
IBM,May 2009,104.85
IBM,Jun 2009,103.01
IBM,Jul 2009,116.34
IBM,Aug 2009,117
IBM,Sep 2009,118.55
IBM,Oct 2009,119.54
IBM,Nov 2009,125.79
IBM,Dec 2009,130.32
IBM,Jan 2010,121.85
IBM,Feb 2010,127.16
IBM,Mar 2010,125.55
AAPL,Jan 2000,25.94
AAPL,Feb 2000,28.66
AAPL,Mar 2000,33.95
AAPL,Apr 2000,31.01
AAPL,May 2000,21
AAPL,Jun 2000,26.19
AAPL,Jul 2000,25.41
AAPL,Aug 2000,30.47
AAPL,Sep 2000,12.88
AAPL,Oct 2000,9.78
AAPL,Nov 2000,8.25
AAPL,Dec 2000,7.44
AAPL,Jan 2001,10.81
AAPL,Feb 2001,9.12
AAPL,Mar 2001,11.03
AAPL,Apr 2001,12.74
AAPL,May 2001,9.98
AAPL,Jun 2001,11.62
AAPL,Jul 2001,9.4
AAPL,Aug 2001,9.27
AAPL,Sep 2001,7.76
AAPL,Oct 2001,8.78
AAPL,Nov 2001,10.65
AAPL,Dec 2001,10.95
AAPL,Jan 2002,12.36
AAPL,Feb 2002,10.85
AAPL,Mar 2002,11.84
AAPL,Apr 2002,12.14
AAPL,May 2002,11.65
AAPL,Jun 2002,8.86
AAPL,Jul 2002,7.63
AAPL,Aug 2002,7.38
AAPL,Sep 2002,7.25
AAPL,Oct 2002,8.03
AAPL,Nov 2002,7.75
AAPL,Dec 2002,7.16
AAPL,Jan 2003,7.18
AAPL,Feb 2003,7.51
AAPL,Mar 2003,7.07
AAPL,Apr 2003,7.11
AAPL,May 2003,8.98
AAPL,Jun 2003,9.53
AAPL,Jul 2003,10.54
AAPL,Aug 2003,11.31
AAPL,Sep 2003,10.36
AAPL,Oct 2003,11.44
AAPL,Nov 2003,10.45
AAPL,Dec 2003,10.69
AAPL,Jan 2004,11.28
AAPL,Feb 2004,11.96
AAPL,Mar 2004,13.52
AAPL,Apr 2004,12.89
AAPL,May 2004,14.03
AAPL,Jun 2004,16.27
AAPL,Jul 2004,16.17
AAPL,Aug 2004,17.25
AAPL,Sep 2004,19.38
AAPL,Oct 2004,26.2
AAPL,Nov 2004,33.53
AAPL,Dec 2004,32.2
AAPL,Jan 2005,38.45
AAPL,Feb 2005,44.86
AAPL,Mar 2005,41.67
AAPL,Apr 2005,36.06
AAPL,May 2005,39.76
AAPL,Jun 2005,36.81
AAPL,Jul 2005,42.65
AAPL,Aug 2005,46.89
AAPL,Sep 2005,53.61
AAPL,Oct 2005,57.59
AAPL,Nov 2005,67.82
AAPL,Dec 2005,71.89
AAPL,Jan 2006,75.51
AAPL,Feb 2006,68.49
AAPL,Mar 2006,62.72
AAPL,Apr 2006,70.39
AAPL,May 2006,59.77
AAPL,Jun 2006,57.27
AAPL,Jul 2006,67.96
AAPL,Aug 2006,67.85
AAPL,Sep 2006,76.98
AAPL,Oct 2006,81.08
AAPL,Nov 2006,91.66
AAPL,Dec 2006,84.84
AAPL,Jan 2007,85.73
AAPL,Feb 2007,84.61
AAPL,Mar 2007,92.91
AAPL,Apr 2007,99.8
AAPL,May 2007,121.19
AAPL,Jun 2007,122.04
AAPL,Jul 2007,131.76
AAPL,Aug 2007,138.48
AAPL,Sep 2007,153.47
AAPL,Oct 2007,189.95
AAPL,Nov 2007,182.22
AAPL,Dec 2007,198.08
AAPL,Jan 2008,135.36
AAPL,Feb 2008,125.02
AAPL,Mar 2008,143.5
AAPL,Apr 2008,173.95
AAPL,May 2008,188.75
AAPL,Jun 2008,167.44
AAPL,Jul 2008,158.95
AAPL,Aug 2008,169.53
AAPL,Sep 2008,113.66
AAPL,Oct 2008,107.59
AAPL,Nov 2008,92.67
AAPL,Dec 2008,85.35
AAPL,Jan 2009,90.13
AAPL,Feb 2009,89.31
AAPL,Mar 2009,105.12
AAPL,Apr 2009,125.83
AAPL,May 2009,135.81
AAPL,Jun 2009,142.43
AAPL,Jul 2009,163.39
AAPL,Aug 2009,168.21
AAPL,Sep 2009,185.35
AAPL,Oct 2009,188.5
AAPL,Nov 2009,199.91
AAPL,Dec 2009,210.73
AAPL,Jan 2010,192.06
AAPL,Feb 2010,204.62
AAPL,Mar 2010,223.02
</pre>
    <form>
      <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="multiples" checked> Multiples</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="stacked"> Stacked</label>
    </form>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://raw.github.com/mbostock/d3/master/lib/colorbrewer/colorbrewer.js"></script>
    <script>

    (function() {
        //  1: Modify here to set up you own data
        var parseTimeFormat = "%b %Y"; // specify the time format reading time attribute in file.
        var timeFormat = "%b %Y"; // specify the time format for x axis.
        var nameOfFile = "streamgraph1.csv"; // name and path to the file
        var delimiter = "," ; // specify delimiter of file
        /* Examples for delimiters: 
            vertical bar:   "|" 
            semicolon:      ";" 
            comma:          "," 
            space:          " " 
            tab:            "\t"
            modify below if you data is embedded with the <pre> tag --> comment out '--file' lines
        End of modification */
        // end modify
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse,
              formatYear = d3.format("02d"),
              formatDate = function(d) { return formatYear(d.getFullYear()); };

        var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 60},
              width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
              height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
              lineheight = height;

        var yScaleStacked = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
              yScaleMultiples = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
              xScale = d3.time.scale().rangeRound([0, width]),
              colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal().range(colorbrewer.Blues[5].reverse());

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(xScale)
              .orient("bottom")
              .ticks(d3.time.years)
              .tickFormat(formatDate);

        var stack = d3.layout.stack()
              .offset("wiggle")
              .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
              .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
              .y(function(d) { return d.value; });

        var nest = d3.nest()
              .key(function(d) { return d.group; });

        var areaStacked = d3.svg.area()
              .interpolate("cardinal")
              .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
              .y0(function(d) { return yScaleStacked(d.y0); })
              .y1(function(d) { return yScaleStacked(d.y0 + d.y); });

        var areaMultiples = d3.svg.area()
              .interpolate("cardinal")
              .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
              .y0(function(d) { return lineheight; })
              .y1(function(d) { return yScaleMultiples(d.value); });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
              .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
              .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        // 1 + 2: comment out the next two lines for embedded version 
        // 1: var dsv = d3.dsv(delimiter, "text/plain");        
        //  2: dsv(nameOfFile, function (error, data) {

        // --embedded: comment out next line for file version
        var data = d3.csv.parse( d3.select("pre#data").text() ); // 3: :
        console.log("initial data: ", data);

        data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.group = d.symbol
          d.date = parseDate(d.date);
          d.value = +d.price;
        });

        data.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a.date - b.date;
        });

        var nested = nest.entries(data);
        // console.log("Array nested", nested);

        var layers = stack(nested);

        lineheight = height / nested.length;

        xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        yScaleStacked.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);
        yScaleMultiples.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]).range([lineheight, 0]);

        var group = svg.selectAll(".group")
            .data(layers)
          .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "group")
            .attr("id", function(d){ return d.key})
            .attr('transform', function(d, i){ return "translate(0," + (height - (i+1) * lineheight) +")"; });

        group.append("text")
            .attr("class", "group-label")
            .attr("x", -6)
            .attr('transform', function(d, i){ return "translate(0," + (lineheight - 6) +")"; })
            .text(function(d) { return d.key; });

        group.append("path")
            .attr("class", "layer")
            .attr("d", function(d) { return areaMultiples(d.values); })
            .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colorScale(i); });

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 20) + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        d3.selectAll("input").on("change", change);

        function change() {
          if (this.value === "multiples") transitionMultiples();
          else transitionStacked();
        }

        function transitionMultiples() {
          var t = svg.transition().duration(750),
              g = t.selectAll(".group").attr('transform', function(d, i){ return "translate(0," + (height - (i+1) * lineheight) +")"; });
          g.selectAll(".layer").attr("d", function(d) { return areaMultiples(d.values); });
          g.select(".group-label").attr('transform', function(d, i){ return "translate(0," + (lineheight - 6) +")"; });
        }

        function transitionStacked() {
          var t = svg.transition().duration(750),
              g = t.selectAll(".group").attr('transform', function(){ return "translate(0,0)"; });
          g.selectAll(".layer").attr("d", function(d) { return areaStacked(d.values); });
          g.select(".group-label").attr('transform', function(d, i){ return "translate(0," + yScaleStacked(d.values[0].y0) +")"; });
        }
    // comment out next line for embedded version
    // 4: });
    })()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

After posting and trying; i think I came up with a reasonable solution myself.
In case anyone is interested:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- code until function (which I omit) is the same as above ... -->

    (function() {

        //  1: Modify here to set up you own data
        var parseTimeFormat = "%b %Y"; // specify the time format reading time attribute in file.
        var timeFormat = "%b %Y"; // specify the time format for x axis.
        // var nameOfFile = "streamgraph1.csv"; // name and path to the file
        var nameOfFile = "";
        var delimiter = "," ; // specify delimiter of file
        /* Examples for delimiters: 
            vertical bar:   "|" 
            semicolon:      ";" 
            comma:          "," 
            space:          " " 
            tab:            "\t"
            modify below if you data is embedded with the <pre> tag --> comment out '--file' lines
        End of modification */
        // end modify
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse,
              formatYear = d3.format("02d"),
              formatDate = function(d) { return formatYear(d.getFullYear()); };

        var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 60},
              width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
              height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
              lineheight = height;

        var yScaleStacked = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
              yScaleMultiples = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
              xScale = d3.time.scale().rangeRound([0, width]),
              colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal().range(colorbrewer.Blues[5].reverse());

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(xScale)
              .orient("bottom")
              .ticks(d3.time.years)
              .tickFormat(formatDate);

        var stack = d3.layout.stack()
              .offset("wiggle")
              .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
              .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
              .y(function(d) { return d.value; });

        var nest = d3.nest()
              .key(function(d) { return d.group; });

        var areaStacked = d3.svg.area()
              .interpolate("cardinal")
              .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
              .y0(function(d) { return yScaleStacked(d.y0); })
              .y1(function(d) { return yScaleStacked(d.y0 + d.y); });

        var areaMultiples = d3.svg.area()
              .interpolate("cardinal")
              .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
              .y0(function(d) { return lineheight; })
              .y1(function(d) { return yScaleMultiples(d.value); });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
              .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
              .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        function processData (data) {
            data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.group = d.symbol
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.value = +d.price;
            });

            data.sort(function(a, b) {
              return a.date - b.date;
            });
            return nest.entries(data);
        }

        function render(data) {
            //console.log("data from file2: ", data);
            var nested = processData(data);
            var layers = stack(nested);

            lineheight = height / nested.length;

            xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
            yScaleStacked.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);
            yScaleMultiples.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]).range([lineheight, 0]);

            var group = svg.selectAll(".group")
                .data(layers)
              .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "group")
                .attr("id", function(d){ return d.key})
                .attr('transform', function(d, i){ return "translate(0," + (height - (i+1) * lineheight) +")"; });

            group.append("text")
                .attr("class", "group-label")
                .attr("x", -6)
                .attr('transform', function(d, i){ return "translate(0," + (lineheight - 6) +")"; })
                .text(function(d) { return d.key; });

            group.append("path")
                .attr("class", "layer")
                .attr("d", function(d) { return areaMultiples(d.values); })
                .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colorScale(i); });

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 20) + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            d3.selectAll("input").on("change", change);

            function change() {
              if (this.value === "multiples") transitionMultiples();
              else transitionStacked();
            }

            function transitionMultiples() {
              var t = svg.transition().duration(750),
                  g = t.selectAll(".group").attr('transform', function(d, i){ return "translate(0," + (height - (i+1) * lineheight) +")"; });
              g.selectAll(".layer").attr("d", function(d) { return areaMultiples(d.values); });
              g.select(".group-label").attr('transform', function(d, i){ return "translate(0," + (lineheight - 6) +")"; });
            }

            function transitionStacked() {
              var t = svg.transition().duration(750),
                  g = t.selectAll(".group").attr('transform', function(){ return "translate(0,0)"; });
              g.selectAll(".layer").attr("d", function(d) { return areaStacked(d.values); });
              g.select(".group-label").attr('transform', function(d, i){ return "translate(0," + yScaleStacked(d.values[0].y0) +")"; });
            }
        }

        if (nameOfFile != "") {
            var dsv = d3.dsv(delimiter, "text/plain");      
            dsv(nameOfFile, function (error, data) {
                console.log("data from file: ", data);
                render(data);
            });
        }
        else {
            var data = d3.csv.parse( d3.select("pre#data").text() ); 
            console.log("embedded: ", data);
            render(data);
        }
    })()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems very simple. why not test a variable and call dsv when necessary?

Comment: I agree it must be very simple. I just started with d3 and javascript and my solution is very awkward since I comment out the beginning and the very end of a large block. that way, I cann't test a variable before. 
I think anyone with experience in javascript can suggest how to quickly change the control strucrture (maybe pack the big block in a function ?) such that a simple extra line with a test would work nicely. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Finally, I think I have a reasonable solution.
Thanks In code veritas for encouraging me :)

I will post my solution above...

Comment: Great. Next time post it as an answer in its own box, though. That may help someone in the future with the same problem see how you worked through the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your last section, check the variable's existence this way, rather than whether it is value is `""`. This is more logical and semantic.

```
    if (typeof nameOfFile !== 'undefined') {
        var dsv = d3.dsv(delimiter, "text/plain");      
        dsv(nameOfFile, function (error, data) {
            console.log("data from file: ", data);
            render(data);
        });
    }
    else {
        var data = d3.csv.parse( d3.select("pre#data").text() ); 
        console.log("embedded: ", data);
        render(data);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to post the code as a comment and didn't see I can post an extra answer. I will do it next time!

I will use your if condition. Then I just comment our the definition of nameOfFile when I don't load from a file.